# Ajax request for file to be processed in JS on client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, file-handling

This is a very general question:

I would like to download a file from the server that is only available after some input-dependent processing was done on the server via an AJAX request (e.g. using jQuery). However, I don't want to pass that file explicitly to the user as a download in the browser.

Instead, I would like to use the file for displaying some figures, which I want to create on the client-side in JavaScript because they are dynamic (specifically, can be modified by the user with sliders). As a backend, I am using Django.

Any thoughts/code on how to do this exactly, or alternatively reasons why the pipeline I imagine is not a good idea?

Comment: It's more useful to explain directly what you want that trying to explain an analogy of this one... What you want to do concretly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code retrieves a photo as a blob from he server and then sets SRC to it when/where needed.

```
       xmlhttp.open('GET', PHOTO_URL, true);
       xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var blob = xmlhttp.response;
                    photoImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    setTimeout(setOnCampusImage,0);     
                } else {
                    photoImg.src = 'unknown.png';
                }
            }
        }
```